# ngClass for multi conditional numbers

Tags: angular

I want to change the class name base on the score of the user.

For instance, if the user gets less than or equal to 30, class name should be `beginner`, if the user gets between 31-75 then the class name should be `intermediate`. If the user gets above 76 then the class name is `expert`.

So far I have this which isn't what I need exactly:

```
[ngClass]="marks.score<=30 ? 'beginner' : 'expert'"
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
[ngClass]="marks.score <= 30 ? 'beginner' : marks.score > 30 && marks.score <= 75 ? 'intermediate': 'expert'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple classes, each with a condition:

```ts
[ngClass]="{'beginner': marks.score <= 30, 'intermediate': marks.score >= 31 || marks.score <= 75, 'expert': marks.score >= 76}"
```

With the object syntax each key is the class name and the value is the expression to determine if the class is present.

`{ 'className': expression, ... }`

Answer (score 1):

An option you can consider it using a [custom pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes) that takes the score number value and returns a string for the CSS class. This would be used in combination with `[class]` The advantage would be that Pipes do a great job to cache values, so if a score number value is ever repeated, the pipe will be able to return that cached value:

Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "marks"
})
export class MarksPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number, args?: any): string {
    if (value >= 76) {
      return "expert";
    } else if (value > 30 && value <= 75) {
      return "intermediate";
    } else if (value <= 30) {
      return "beginner";
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }
}
```

Template (example usage with different score values):

```
<div [class]="30 | marks">beginner</div>
<div [class]="65 | marks">intermediate</div>
<div [class]="82 | marks">expert</div>
```

Or if you need to use `ngClass` for CSS class merging:

```
<div class="foo" [ngClass]="30 | marks">beginner</div>
<div class="bar" [ngClass]="65 | marks">intermediate</div>
<div class="baz" [ngClass]="82 | marks">expert</div>
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ty5whv) in action.

Answer (score 0):

In your css file

```
.beginner {color: red}
.intermediate{color: yellow}
.expert { color: green}
.other { color: pink}
```

In your typescript file

```
marks = [10, 20, 30, 40 , 50 , 60 , 70 , 80, 90, 100, 110, 120];

  getClass(mark){
    if(mark <= 30)
    return 'beginner';
    else if (mark <= 75)
    return 'intermediate';
    else if (mark <= 100)
    return 'expert';
    else return 'other';
  }
```

In your html

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let mark of marks">
        <div [ngClass]="getClass(mark)">{{ mark }}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-class-example)